# What is the relation between frequency of piezo element and its shape?

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I was reading about piezo elements and its frequency.

I found on the internet that : The composition of the ceramic material and the shape and volume of the element determine the resonance frequency -- generally, a thicker element has a lower resonance frequency than a thinner element of the same shape. [Determining Resonance Frequency](https://www.americanpiezo.com/knowledge-center/piezo-theory/determining-resonance-frequency.html)

I found also that : At ultrasonic frequencies large surface area parts draw considerable current and resistive heating of the electrodes becomes the limiting factor. [Piezo Systems - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.piezo.com/tech3faq.html)

First question, does that mean that if the piezo element is circular has a different frequency as a rectangular piezo element plate when they have the same thickness?

I know that frequency = velocity/(2*thickness)

My second question, what is the relation between frequency of piezo element and its shape?

Comment: You might just want to look up info on standing wave modes that circles vs. rectangles support, for starters.